# How to synchronize an unsynchronized collection in Java

Tags: java, collections, synchronization

In Java, how can I make a not synchronized collection a synchronized one?

Comment: Call `Collections.synchronizedCollection` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the static `Collections.synchronizedCollection` method:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
Collection<Integer> myNumbers = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<Integer>());
myNumbers.add(5);
myNumbers.add(10);
```